# How to cut and paste on Sony XPeria Z1?

Tags: text-editor, text-input

Assuming a healthy phone, what is the normal procedure for *cutting* and pasting from *editable* text fields on Android?

On my iPhone this pops up after selecting text, but I cannot even select the text on Android. The whole process is so intuitive on iOS I cannot even remember how I do it, it just happens naturally. On Android I can't work it out!

I'm mostly interested in version 4.2.2 and the multi-line plain text input used on the Wordpress app, though I have equal trouble with Notes and Chrome's address bar.

I want to occasionally move sentences around within a chunk of text, without duplicating them (so Copy is of limited interest, though I note it is equally difficult).

I have a Sony XPeria Z1.

**NOTE: this question is about cutting, not copying. Thanks.**

Comment: On Android, it's normally almost the exact same process as iOS. Long-press the text. drag the end-points, then click the Copy/Cut options. The only difference between Android and iOS is that on Android, the Copy/Cut buttons are on the top of the screen. Although it's possible that Samsung/Whoever has made the process different on their phones. Could you please [edit] your question and add information about which phone you have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Sony, on their phones you [double tap](http://userguide.sonymobile.com/referrer.php?region=global-en&product=xperia-z1#!Editing-text.html) a word and some draggable gadgets will appear. Cut, copy etc appear at the top edge.

Comment: Wow. Changing from the OS standard long-tap to double-tap just makes things harder for no apparent reason. Good work, Sony.

Comment: Worse, they left the standard in place half the time. For Chrome (and probably others) both standards on one screen.

Answer (score 2):

Android 4.2.2 already contains the advanced copy/cut/paste functions. Calling it up is intuitive too - just long press on a word, then use the field edge indicator gadgets to select the text you want to cut.

[image]

Then on top you will see some icons representing specific functions. There will be a copy one (Number 4 in the image above), a paste one (Number 5), and a cut icon too (Number 3).

Pasting works the same way, just long press where you want to paste, and press the button.

Comment: This answer is perfect, although "field edge indicator gadget" had me stumped for a moment. Is that the official name for the end-point things?

Comment: @dotVezz No, they're called *text selection handles*.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, yes, the official name evaded me a bit.
Also, the image seems to be from a non-AOSP ROM - on AOSP the icons are a bit different, and cut has definitely no scissor icon (on my phone, running CM10.2 it is as I described before).

Comment: The image is from the Sony website linked in Mr Gibbs's answer.